# Qt include path being ignored?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I'm importing a internal library and have used the Qt Creators wizard.
What that does, is it just adds the

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../lib_directory 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib_directory
```

`lib_directory` contains the source and header files for the library.

In the source file of the project where I need to use the library methods, the include isn't working with the relative path.

I have to do:

```
#include "../lib_directory/libheader.h"
```

because

```
#include "libheader.h"
```

complains about a nonexistent file. Am I missing something?

Comment: You might try '#include <libheader.h>' instead.

Comment: @vahancho Tried it, didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$$PWD` is the path of the `.pro` file being parsed at the time the variable is encountered. If your `$$PWD` is in an include file, you may want to use `$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_` instead, as this points to path of the project file, not any of its includes.

Your use of `$$PWD` implies the following tree - is that the case?

```
lib_directory
foo
  foo.pro    ---- containing your INCLUDEPATH
  foo.cpp    ---- where only #include "../lib_directory/libheader.h" works
```

Comment: Yes, the .pro file was located in the subproject which is why the path with the $PWD didn't work.